# Bone rotation problem

Tags: armature, bones, shape-keys, axis

I set a bone to copy rotation of the arm bone when it rotates on Z axis to enable a corrective shape key. The problem is that when i rotate the arm on the X axis, the bone that is copying rotation rotates on Z axis and enables the corrective shape key, distorting the mesh.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you rotate Arm1.L on the global X axis, it will make it rotate a bit on its local Z axis a bit, as this bone is not completely align on the global axis. Is it your problem here?

Comment: Yes, the bone shouldn't rotate on Z axis when I rotate it on X axis.

Comment: well, as I say, it does, as it is not completely aligned with the global X axis, rotating the bone on the global X axis makes it rotate on its local Z, if you align it completely with the global X axis, it won't happen any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your bone is not completely aligned with the global X axis, rotating it on the global X axis makes it rotate on its local Z. If you align it completely with the global X axis in *Edit* mode, it won't happen any more. Once aligned:

[image]

Not sure why you need to rotate it on the global X axis though, just keyframe rotations on its local Y axis.

Comment: I don't know how to align the bones, is it putting them straight in line? because it didn't worked, tried going to armature and clear rolls and other options there, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: S Z 0, S Y 0, and Shift N > Global + X Axis